# How to extract some resources from JAR via Maven?

Tags: java, regex, maven, jar, resources

I have a Maven project which downloads a number of JAR-s from repository and packages then packs them all into a ZIP. What I need to do is to copy a number of resources from those placed in a certain directory outside of the JAR-s before zipping. Example:

```
bundle/
   dir1/
       jar1.jar
       jar2.jar
   dir2/
       jar3.jar
       jar4.jar
```

All the JAR-s contain a resource named resource.txt. What I need to do is to copy this file from dir2/*.jar to resources/*_resource.txt (* is the JAR's name):

```
bundle/
   dir1/
       jar1.jar
       jar2.jar
   dir2/
       jar3.jar
       jar4.jar
  resources/
       jar3_resource.txt
       jar4_resource.txt
```

The best option would be to specify by regex what to copy and where.

Comment: Are you searching for a pure java solution or one based on a maven-plugin?

Comment: Maven plugin will probably be the best option.

Comment: maven-assembly-plugin should be the best solution. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html for all the options. Also check the examples (in menu on lefthandside of the page). This plugin is designed to gather files/resources from all kinds of locations and to bundle them into a new archive (or directory)